# Date range search in laravel controller

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-8

Suppose I have two data rows in my `orders` table.

```
`order1 created at 2022-06-18`

`order2 created at 2022-06-19`
```

Now while I want to search within `2022-06-18` and `2022-06-19` date it shows only `order1`, but not showing `order2` though `order2` is also created at `2022-06-19` date.

But If I search within `2022-06-18` and `2022-06-20` then both `order1` and `order2` row will return as a result.

Here is my laravel query in controller

```
DB::table('orders')
     ->whereBetween('orders.created_at', [$from_date, $to_date])
     ->get();
```

Is there any problem? Any body help please?

Comment: try passing carbon objects with time. Add `startOfDay` to first date and `endOfDay` to second date. example: `->whereBetween('orders.created_at', [Carbon::parse($from_date).->startOfDay(), Carbon::parse($to_date)->endOfDay()])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `created_at` and `updated_at` "timestamp" field created by laravel migration are of type `DateTime` not just `Date`.

When you run

```
->whereBetween('orders.created_at', ["2022-06-18", "2022-06-19"])
```

It is equivalent to

```
->whereBetween('orders.created_at', ["2022-06-18 00:00:00", "2022-06-19 00:00:00"])
```

But your Order2 has created_at with a different hour/minute/second than "00" on the date "2022-06-19".

That's why you get only one result.

To fix it, either add one day `["2022-06-18", "2022-06-20"]` or specify the hour/minute/second.

```
->whereBetween('orders.created_at', [
    date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($from_date)),
    date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime($to_date)),
])
```

Comment: @N69S....Thanks a lot...It's Done...I But I am impressed for how you explained it !!! Great Explanation !!!

Answer (score 2):

Between always is inlcuding.

In your case the createdat >= '2022-06-18' and <= '2022-06-20'.

Therefore both  rows are included

Comment: @nbk....But I want while I search from '2022-06-18' to '2022-06-19' it wil shows the orders id which created at '2022-06-19' date also.

Comment: as you can see in my answer. the to date is alwqays included there is clearly seen <=. If you want the end date excluded you can't use between

Comment: @nbk he did not explain much, like the field type in the database and such. His database fields "created_at" and "updated_at" are  DateTime type that are auto saved on model change/creation

Comment: @N69S e asked why hos query shows the 18th and the 19th rows, i did explain that and it explains why he can't use between that way, If he asked what can i do your solution or one with smaller as t 19t would be correct, but tat was not his question as i understood it